# Is there a list of AMIs for every popular linux distribution and version

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I need to test a piece of software against every linux distribution/version. I'm going to use amazon AWS Is there a list of AMIs somewhere that I can just copy paste into my script to automate this tedious process?

Answer (score 4):

Amazon provides a list on their website.
https://aws.amazon.com/amis

Actually I was sure that it was also possible to grab and filter the list via the API but unfortunately I can't find any documentation about this (imaginary?) feature

Comment: You can use [ec2-describe-images](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeImages.html) command to search/filter through public amis on aws marketplace, but that won't help you to determine which one is the official release of specific distro

Answer (score 3):

You can get AMI ID from aws site

Below is how to

To find a Linux AMI using the Images page

- Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
- From the navigation bar, select a region. You can select any region that's available to you, regardless of your location. This is the region in which you'll launch your instance.
- In the navigation pane, choose AMIs.
- (Optional) Use the Filter options to scope the list of displayed AMIs to see only the AMIs that interest you. For example, to list all Linux AMIs provided by AWS, select Public images. Choose the Search bar and select Owner from the menu, then select Amazon images. Choose the Search bar again to select Platform and then the operating system from the list provided.
- (Optional) Choose the Show/Hide Columns icon to select which image attributes to display, such as the root device type. Alternatively, you can select an AMI from the list and view its properties in the Details tab.
- The AMI ID for the platform and Distribution you have chosen would be in the AMI ID tab

More detail here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/finding-an-ami.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about other Linux distros, but Ubuntu has their own web page and kinds-of API for official ubuntu ec2 images

- [Machine Consumable Ubuntu Cloud Guest images Availability Data](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images#Machine_Consumable_Ubuntu_Cloud_Guest_images_Availability_Data) (API)
- http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/

And Amazon Linux, which I believe is based on CentOS, http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami